# How to find the correct api version in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I have a question about the usage of apiVersion in Kuberntes.

For example I am trying to deploy traefik 2.2.1 into my kubernetes cluster. I have a traefik middleware deployment definition like this:

```
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: https-redirect
spec:
  redirectScheme:
    scheme: https
    permanent: true
    port: 443
```

When I try to deploy my objects with

```
$ kubectl apply -f middleware.yaml
```

I got the following error message:

```
unable to recognize "middleware.yaml": no matches for kind "Middleware" in version "traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1"
```

The same object works fine with Traefik version 2.2.0 but not with version 2.2.1.

On the traefik documentation there is no example other the ones using the version "traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1"

I dont't hink that my deployment issue is specific to traefik. It is a general problem with conflicting versions. Is there any way how I can figure out which apiVersions are supported in my cluster environment?

There are so many outdated examples posted around using deprecated apiVersions that I wonder if there is some kind of official apiVersion directory for kubernetes? Or maybe there is some kubectl command which I can ask for apiversions?

Comment: Have you installed CRDs?

Comment: yes I think so, traefik is a CRD.

Comment: "traefik is a CRD" --- uhm, I'm not sure this statement makes any sense. CRD is a special type of kubernetes resource and it must be installed, either by you or something else.

Comment: Yes, but if you install traefik in kubernetes you typically install CRDs like this: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/crd-acme/   - so yes think I have installed CRDs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably crds for traefik v2 are not installed. You could use below command which lists the API versions that are available on the Kubernetes cluster.

```
kubectl api-versions | grep traefik
traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
```

Use below command to check crds installed on the Kubernetes cluster.

```
kubectl get crds
NAME                                   CREATED AT
ingressroutes.traefik.containo.us      2020-05-09T13:58:09Z
ingressroutetcps.traefik.containo.us   2020-05-09T13:58:09Z
ingressrouteudps.traefik.containo.us   2020-05-09T13:58:09Z
middlewares.traefik.containo.us        2020-05-09T13:58:09Z
tlsoptions.traefik.containo.us         2020-05-09T13:58:09Z
tlsstores.traefik.containo.us          2020-05-09T13:58:09Z
traefikservices.traefik.containo.us    2020-05-09T13:58:09Z
```

Check traefik v1 vs v2 [here](https://docs.traefik.io/migration/v1-to-v2/)

Comment: Yes this is what I see in my kubernetes cluster. The Middleware object definition in my question is from the official traefik documentation. Why does kubernetes complain about the apiVersion ?

Comment: Maybe my fault is that I apply all CRDs and deployment objects with one 'kubectl apply -f...' command. If I call the apply command for the midelewares (which are defined in CRDs) a view seconds later the message will not occur.

Comment: yeah that can happen..everything you apply with kubectl happens asynchronously and so may take sometime to get committed into etcd and till that time it will not be available to be used

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I just run the kubectl apply again after a few moments it will then work.

Comment: yes this is true. some objects (e.g. middleware) takes some moment to be available and it is sometimes better to create/apply the objects separately by different yaml files.